# Why can my filter query SOME metadata but not other metadata?

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I'm stumped by what seems like a simple task: I want to randomly select a post that fits certain criteria (metadata set by a specific plugin) and then return that random post to the plugin in question. This plugin has a filter that appears perfect for the task, and if I hardcode the post ID all works well.

What's odd is I can't seem to pull the posts I need using `WP_Query`. I know the metadata is *there*, I can see it in phpmyadmin. I can query *other* metadata, just not the metadata set by this plugin.

How can I troubleshoot / further investigate this odd situation? I can't think of any reason why only SOME metadata could be accessed by `WP_Query`.

Just for reference, here's the code from my filter / query.

```
function boxzilla_randomize( $load, $box_id ) {

  $box_args = [
      'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => [
      [
        'key' => 'boxzilla_options',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
      ]
    ]
  ];

  $box_query = new \WP_Query( $box_args );

  if ( $box_query->has_posts() ) {
    write_log("hey, I got one");
  }

  // return $box_id;
}

add_filter( 'boxzilla_load_box', __NAMESPACE__.'\\boxzilla_randomize', 10, 2 );
```

Edit for the purpose of clarifying the question: I see that the metadata exists in the db but a post query always comes up empty.

[image: Empty results querying db]

[image: Meta key visible in phpmyadmin]

Comment: So you want to fetch posts via their post meta values, and randomly select one of the posts retrieved? Keep in mind that ordering things randomly is extremely slow/expensive, and querying things via their post meta values is also very expensive, though not as much as random ordering. Usually when people want a random post, they don't really mean truly random and mean something else, e.g. show a different post each time I refresh the page, but distribute the selection evenly

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right, I'd like to select one of the (2-3 possible) posts with a certain meta value. It's true, the `WP_Query` is slightly blunt tool for the job but for now I would be happy just successfully retrieving the right posts from the db.

Comment: Regarding the troubleshooting, try inspecting the SQL query - `echo $box_query->request;` - is it good? You can also copy the SQL and run it via phpMyAdmin and see if you're getting the expected results that you wanted.

Comment: The query isn't the issue, the query does nothing random because it's not told to, if it produced the desired results with the given options that would be a bug. Instead, where does `boxzilla_options` come from? Given that Boxzilla is a 3rd party premium plugin, have you contacted their support? This Q might be saveable if it's just about grabbing a random post from a query, but if any knowledge at all about boxzilla is required then the Q has to be closed as off topic, and right now there are no boxzilla docs that document this. Can you confirm that the key is exactly `boxzilla_options`?

Comment: @SallyCJ yes, I can run the query successfully in phpmyadmin. I can echo the query as it's run in the filter, and it comes back empty. If I change the criteria to another meta key the query works as I would expect.

Comment: @TomJNowell sorry if I wasn't clear in the initial post, I know there's nothing in the code snippet to randomize results. I was just demonstrating the query itself. The query works with all other meta keys, and yes, the key is exactly `boxzilla_options`

Comment: If all work except that one, you should contact boxzilla support

Comment: @jamesfacts, the reason I suggested echoing the SQL generated via your `WP_Query` call, is that so you could see if there's a plugin/code filtering/altering the query. But basically, if even phpMyAdmin doesn't return any results, then it's likely that you're missing a query arg or not setting it to the correct value(s).

Comment: And in your case, I think the post type is *not* `post` which is the default value if it's not specified when you call `WP_Query`/`get_posts()`. You should be able to find the post type via the relevant admin page, or run this via phpMyAdmin: `SELECT p.ID, p.post_type, p.post_status FROM wp_posts p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID WHERE pm.meta_key = 'boxzilla_options'`

Comment: @SallyCJ you are 100% correct—the post type turns out to be a custom post type, which I did not anticipate. That was the issue I had all along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should work as is. To test this, I created 4 posts, and then using WP CLI, ran:

```
wp post meta add 10 boxzilla_options "testingtesting123"
```

Where post 10 is a post with the title test. 3 other posts existed that did not have the post meta.

To test that the post meta key/value pair did indeed exist, I ran this code:

```php
wp> get_post_meta( 10 );
=> array(2) {
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "1571337707:1"
  }
  ["boxzilla_options"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "testingtesting123"
  }
}
```

I then opened `wp shell` and ran this code:

```php
wp> $args = ['post_status' => 'publish', 'meta_query' => [['key' => 'boxzilla_options','compare' => 'EXISTS']] ];
=> array(2) {
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(16) "boxzilla_options"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(6) "EXISTS"
    }
  }
}
wp> $posts = get_posts( $args );
```

The resulting `$posts` array contained the desired post with ID 10:

```php
wp> $posts = get_posts( $args );
=> array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Post)#1903 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(10)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-10-17 18:44:10"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
etc...
```

Thus, the problem is likely the Boxzilla plugin, which means that further help on WPSE is not possible. **You should contact Boxzilla support**

Comment: Thank you for double-checking my syntax, and I'm grateful for the `wp shell` demo, I didn't realize the CLI offered that feature. You're absolutely right it must be something in Boxzilla, I just wasn't sure if there was a subtle requirement in building meta queries I might have missed.

Comment: Yeah you were on the right track, and it should have worked for you, whatever's going on is some sort of interference